# HTML/CSS What is the name of the effect, video link pops on same page and background darkens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

First of all, im lurking for the last week and it very much helped me build the page with basically zero no none prior knowledge, thank you so much!

But now i want to build an effect and i cant search for it because i dont know what to search for. Can you help me get a name for that, im almost certain i can figure it out myself from there.

I want it so that when im clicking a picture which leads to a video it does not link me to a new page but playes the video with some custom text beneath on the same page and blacks out the environment, like a *cinema mode*? Like a popup on the same page which darkens the page behind.

Comment: A [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)?

Comment: found it over the modal, i was looking for a lightbox. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the user click the image and the video starts you can set the background color with the rgba function (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp).

With the alpha parameter you can set the opacity for your background, for example:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black with opacity */
}
```

Look to exclude the video element from this behaviour.